# Polymorphism with a friend function in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, friend

I would like to combine the concepts of polymorphism and friendship. I am making a pure virtual member function of a base class a friend of another class. I would then like to override this pure virtual member function in the classes derived from that base class, and access private member data of the class who has such function as friend. See the code snippet below. The compiler complains when I refer to `my_int` in the derived classes member function `add()`. I understand friendship is a 1-to-1 relationship, but I wonder if there is any way around it so as to implement polymorphism. Do I just have to make the member functions of the different derived classes friends of the `foo()` class?

```
class foo {
private:
    int my_int{};
public:
    friend virtual int base::add();
};

class base {
public:
    virtual int add() = 0;
};

class derived_1 : public base {
public:
    int add() {
        return my_int + 1;
    }
};

class derived_2 : public base {
public:
    int add() {
        return my_int + 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: `my_int` is defined in `foo`, `derived_1` doesn't have a `foo` object, it couldn't access `foo::my_int` even if `foo::my_int` was public. This has got nothing  to do with public, private, friendship or polymorphism. To access a member of a class, you must have an object of that class. That's the fundamental problem here. Either you have seriously misunderstood something or this code does not illustrate what you are actually trying to do..

Comment: @john That is really true, I was thinking about it very wrongly. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, with what you've displayed it's not going to work because my_int is a member of foo but in the base class tree there is no 'foo' to get the member from.

The easy answer would be to make the function take an int argument and do away with the use of friend entirely.

```
struct derived2 : base
{
  int add(int arg) { return arg + 2; }
};
```

The use of 'friend' should make you seriously question whether what you are doing is a good answer, sometimes the answer to that question is 'yes' but not often. And the more friends you need the less often the answer remains 'yes'.

Another way would be to add a function to base:

```
int get_arg(foo & f) { return f.my_int; }
```

and make that function the friend rather than add, get_arg() would be called from each derived's add() in order to get the value to work with but get_arg is not itself virtual.

Comment: You're absolutely correct on both counts: 1) it's probably better if the OP doesn't need "friend" in the first place.  2) If he does, then he should make the friend method a "facade" that "delegates the work to a helper member function that is virtual".  Approach 2) is illustrated by `<<` in the example I cited below.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look here:

> https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Virtual_Friend_Function
>
> **Intent**
>
> Simulate a virtual friend function.
>
> **Solution and Sample Code**
>
> Virtual friend function idiom makes use of an extra indirection to
>   achieve the desired effect of dynamic binding for friend functions. In
>   this idiom, usually there is only one function that is a friend of the
>   base class of the hierarchy and the friend function simply delegates
>   the work to a helper member function that is virtual. The helper
>   function is overridden in every derived class, which does the real job
>   and the friend function just serves as a facade.
>
> ```
> class Base {
>   public:
>     friend ostream& operator << (ostream& o, const Base& b);
>     // ...
>   protected:
>     virtual void print(ostream& o) const
>     { ... }
> };
> /* make sure to put this function into the header file */
> inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const Base& b)
> {
>   b.print(o); // delegate the work to a polymorphic member function.
>   return o;
> }
>
> class Derived : public Base {
>   protected:
>     virtual void print(ostream& o) const
>     { ... }
> };
> ```

Comment: +1 Thank you for your input. It turns out I had not used friend functions for a while and somehow forgot what it grants you access to is the private data of an object, not of the class itself as I was trying in my example.

Comment: For your example to work, wouldn't the operator << have to take in as argument a pointer to a base object? And then call ```b->print(o)``` for polymorphism to work. Also, why is the ```print``` function ```virtual``` in the ```Derived``` class? Maybe I misunderstood the method you are describing.